# In Inkscape, how can I easily select multiple objects that are obscured by other objects?

Tags: inkscape, selections

I have object 1 which obscures object 2 which obscures object 3 which obscures object 4.

> **Object 1**
>       **Object 2**
>           **Object 3**
>                **Object 4**

I know I can <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + **click** to select contiguous objects in the stack, but I want **objects 1** and **3** selected, **excluding 2** and **4**.

Is there a way to quickly achieve such selection without having to rely on the **XML Editor**?

Thanks.

Comment: I sometimes do this sort of thing by moving the objects off the top of each other so they don't overlap (so much) then select the things I want. Then Ctrl+Z to undo the movements I just did. The objects I selected *remain selected* throughout the undo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By far the easiest and quickest way to do this is to rely on the fact that undo in inkscape does not undo selection.

1. Move the objects off each other so you can see them all (and click on them)
2. Select the objects 1 and 3.
3. Undo the Moves you did in step 1 with `Edit > Undo`

Objects 1 and 3 will still be selected even after the undo operations.

Comment: Wow, didn't know this after using Inkscape for 10+ years. Great answer!

Answer (score 8):

In new Inkscape 0.92 you can select it by holding <kbd>alt</kbd> with **scrolling 
mouse**.

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + **`Mouse Scroll`** will add to selection

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you hold down the Shift and Alt keys as well as hold down the life mouse button, you can draw over the object you want to select.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the shift key for this purpose

Shift + Left Mouse Click to select multiple objects